# Cannot web-scrape cause cannot find the form element

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler

Trying to scrape the following site:
https://israeldrugs.health.gov.il/#!/byDrug

You need to enter a search term in the form and press the blue button on the left.

However, failed with bs4 because it cannot find the form element.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data on this site is loaded dynamically, using javascript. If you dig into the XHRs (using the Developer tab in your browser), you'll see how this information is loaded into the page. BTW, the following assumes you're using python; if not you'll have to find an equivalent in another language.

```
import requests
import json

target = 'ATORVASTATIN AS CALCIUM' #this is just a random drug from their list
data = '{"val":"'+target+'","prescription":false,"healthServices":false,"pageIndex":1,"orderBy":0}'


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Origin': 'https://israeldrugs.health.gov.il',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://israeldrugs.health.gov.il/',
}

response = requests.post('https://israeldrugs.health.gov.il/GovServiceList/IDRServer/SearchByName', headers=headers,  data=data)

#load the json response
meds = json.loads(response.text)
#a random item from the 8th (random, again) drug in the response
meds['results'][7]['dragHebName']
```

output:

```
'טורבה 10'
```

Comment: Any suggestions how to scrape the whole database?
I was hoping to get access to the link to the specific records and go from there

Comment: @gtomer Not sure; it may be possible, but it will require a much deeper dive into the structure of the website. You may want to post it as a separate question and see what people come up with.

Comment: can you try your solution again. It does not seem to work anymore

Answer (score 1):

dunno if its still relevant but i was able scraping the whole database (or at least most of it) with node js & puppeteer (needed it for a personal project).

```js
// after intalling puppeteer with npm i
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

// using fulesystem to save scraped data to json file
const fs = require('fs');

const scrape = async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    // go to the url and wait until it loads
    await
    page.goto(`https://israeldrugs.health.gov.il/#!/byDrug`, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
        timeout : 0
    });   
    const searchInputSelector  = '#homeCtrl > div.display-wrapper > ui-view > div > div > div.search-textbox-container > idr-search-textbox > div:nth-child(1) > div > form > input' 
    await page.waitForSelector(searchInputSelector)

    // grabbing search input field and typing 'a' inside. this will fetch most of the data base (as it searches char at the WHOLE string of the commercial & generic names
    await page.type(searchInputSelector, 'a')
    const searchButtonSelector = '#homeCtrl > div.display-wrapper > ui-view > div > div > div.search-textbox-container > idr-search-textbox > div:nth-child(1) > div > div'

    // grabbing search button & clicking it
    await page.click(searchButtonSelector)

    // starting to create database array
    fs.writeFileSync('israMeds.json', '[')
    const pagesSelector = '#homeCtrl > div.display-wrapper > ui-view > div > search-list > div > div > div.compareAndSortBarWrap > div > div.checkbox.selectAll > span'
    await page.waitForSelector(pagesSelector)

    // grabbing number of results. divided by 10 it will give number of pages to scrape
    const pagesNum = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const pagesSelector = '#homeCtrl > div.display-wrapper > ui-view > div > search-list > div > div > div.compareAndSortBarWrap > div > div.checkbox.selectAll > span'
        return +document.querySelector(pagesSelector).textContent.trim().split('').filter(x => !isNaN(x)).join('').trim() / 10 + 1
    })
    const roundPages = Math.floor(pagesNum)
    for (let i = 0; i < roundPages; i++){
    if (i !== 0 ) fs.appendFileSync('israMeds.json',',')
    await page.waitForNetworkIdle(page,500,0)
    const elements = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const resultSelector = '#homeCtrl > div.display-wrapper > ui-view > div > search-list > div > div > div.search_wrap.ng-scope > div'
        
        return
        // grabbing results selector and looping over them. here you can choose your desired data by getting the field's html selector
        [...document.querySelectorAll(resultSelector)]
       .map(el => {
        const hebTitleSelector = 'div.infoText > div > div > div.firstRowTitle.ng-binding'   
        const engTitleSelector = 'div.infoText > div > div > div > span'
        const activeIngredientSelector = 'div.infoText > div > div > div.secondRowTitle.moreInfo.ng-binding.ng-scope'
        // creating object out of the desired data
        return JSON.stringify({
               drugHebTitle : el.querySelector(hebTitleSelector).textContent,
               drugEngTitle : el.querySelector(engTitleSelector).textContent,
               activeIngredient : el.querySelector(activeIngredientSelector).textContent.trim().split(' ')[2]
           })
       })
    })

    // adding data to external json file
    fs.appendFileSync('israMeds.json',elements.toString())
    const nextPageSelector = '#homeCtrl > div.display-wrapper > ui-view > div > search-list > div > div > div.text-center > ul > li:nth-child(8) > a'
    // moving to next result page
    await page.click(nextPageSelector)
}
    await browser.close();
    fs.appendFileSync('israMeds.json', ']')
};
```